# Replace every element with the next greatest?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given an unsorted array, assign every element to its immediate larger number after the current number, assign to -1 if no such number exists
Eg. 3 1 2 5 9 4 8 should be converted to
5 2 5 9 -1 8 -1

O(nlogn) or O(n) approach ?

Comment: you might consider to reformulate your question and add some appropriate tags to it.

Comment: What exactly do you want? An algorithm or pseudo code? Any specific language choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a way to do it in `O(nlogn)` :-

```
int newarr[];   
MinHeap heap; 
heap.push(0);  
for(int i=1;i<n;i++) { 
  while(arr[heap.top()]<arr[i]) {    
      k = heap.pop();
      newarr[k] = arr[i];
  }    
  heap.push(arr[i]);

} 

// No larger elements

while(!heap.isEmpty) {
  k = heap.pop();
  newarr[k] = -1;

}
```

**Time Complexity :** There are only n inserts and n deletes possible in the heap from the above code hence it is `O(nlogn)` where it take `O(logn)` for insert and delete in heap

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sketch of a `n log(n)` solution:

```
copy your array in copy:                           O(n)
sort copy:                                         O(n log(n))
for each i in input:                               (n loops)
    perform a dichotomic search to find i in copy. O(log(n))  
    replace i in input                             O(1)            
=> loop is in                                      O(n log(n))
```

There are several place where it could be optimized, but I seriously doubt there could be an asymptotically better (eg: `O(n)`) algorithm. The reason is that if instead of replacing each number but the *value* of the next number you write the *position* of the next number then you have a sorted linked list in your array and sorting is know to be at least `O(n log(n))`. However, I agree that is is not a real proof and I might be wrong.